# When do registrar's offices usually request course schedules?

Tags: administration

At approximately what time in the fall semester, do most universities (in the US, say) request that departments submit their spring schedules?

At my university, the date keeps moving earlier and earlier; this year, it is on the second day of classes. This causes difficulties for us, as we don't have adequate time to meet with each other or our students to discuss the department's needs. Is such an early date typical?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but I've observed the same thing, and can state a general rule: The larger the university, the more likely it is that administrative departments operate for their own convenience rather than for the convenience of either students or faculty.

Comment: @BobBrown - that rule applies to any human organization as far as I can tell. On the other hand, back in the old days, I can remember knowing the spring before what classes I could/would take for the following year. This knowledge was based on printed course catalogs. So, the department figured students' needs in the spring term, so were ready to go on decisions...

Comment: It used to be that the administrative departments existed to support the Academic / teaching staff, now it appears that the shoe is on the other foot.. Seems to be the same attitude where I am, admin looking for schedules for next semester before we have even started the final exams of the current semester...